# Mac-Intellij Community-Smart Tomcat-HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: spring, macos, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I trying to setup the spring-mvc project on intellij community edition 2019-3 on mac. I am using smart tomcat for it.

I am trying the example given by journalDev https://www.journaldev.com/14476/spring-mvc-example

It's getting build successfully.

Stacktrace

```
"/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/bin/commons-daemon.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-i18n-ko.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/el-api.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-websocket.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/jasper.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/jasper-el.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-util.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-i18n-de.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/catalina-storeconfig.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/jsp-api.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/catalina-tribes.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-i18n-cs.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/catalina.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-jni.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-i18n-pt-BR.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/ecj-4.13.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/websocket-api.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/catalina-ha.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-api.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/annotations-api.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/jaspic-api.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-i18n-zh-CN.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/catalina-ant.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/servlet-api.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-util-scan.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-i18n-ru.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar:/Users/slandge/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Users/slandge/.SmartTomcat/spring-mvc-example/spring-mvc-example/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Users/slandge/.SmartTomcat/spring-mvc-example/spring-mvc-example/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Users/slandge/.SmartTomcat/spring-mvc-example/spring-mvc-example/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Users/slandge/.SmartTomcat/spring-mvc-example/spring-mvc-example/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.29
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 16 2019 17:29:07 UTC
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.29.0
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.14.5
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           11.0.4+10-b520.11
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            JetBrains s.r.o
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/slandge/.SmartTomcat/spring-mvc-example/spring-mvc-example
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/slandge/.SmartTomcat/spring-mvc-example/spring-mvc-example
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/slandge/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [503] milliseconds
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 12, 2019 7:18:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [338] milliseconds
http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-example
```

When I am trying to access the above url. I am getting below error.

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /spring-mvc-example/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.29

Following are the run configuration

[image: run_configuration]

Comment: Д\ 15 купийти за сидками нельяз  ЖВ